# Which conditions to put on a one-parameter family of measurable functions so that they are all defined in the same set?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

While working on a certain problem (some details below, in case they are useful) I come up with a family of (Borel) measurable functions indexed by a parameter $t$ and defined only almost everywhere. That is
$$ f(\,\cdot\,;t)\colon M_t\subset\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R},\qquad \forall t \in [0, 1],$$
where the only thing that I know in principle about $M_t$ is that 
$$\lvert \mathbb{R}^n\setminus M_t\rvert=0.$$
I would like to prove that I can take a common set $M\subset \mathbb{R}^n$, such that $\lvert \mathbb{R}^n\setminus M\rvert=0$ and $M\subset M_t$ for all $t\in [0, 1]$. That is, I would like to show that I can take a full set in which all of the $f(\,\cdot\,;t)$ are defined at once.

What I do know is that I can take an approximating sequence $f_j(\,\cdot\,;t)$ consisting of smooth functions with compact support with the following properties for $j\to \infty$:
$$ \begin{cases} \displaystyle
\lVert f(\,\cdot\,; t)-f_j(\,\cdot\,;t)\rVert_2\to 0\ & \forall t\in[0,1] \\ \\ \displaystyle
\sup_{s\in[0,1]} \lvert f_j(x\,; s)\rvert \to f^\star(x) & \forall x \in M_0
\end{cases}$$
where $M_0\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a full set (I mean, the complementary $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus M_0$ has null measure) and $f^\star$ is a measurable function.

> > **Question**. Can I conclude that all of the $\{ f(\,\cdot\,;t) \}_{t\in (0,1)}$ are defined in $M_0$?

---

*Details*. Actually I am considering the Schrödinger group 
$$S_t u(x)=\left(e^{it\Delta}u\right)(x).\qquad u \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$$
and the associated *maximal function*
$$S^\star u(x)=\sup_{t\in (0,1)}\left\lvert e^{it\Delta} u(x)\right\rvert.$$
In the question above I have put $f(\, \cdot\, ;t)=S_t u$. Note that this is defined for each $t$, but for only almost all $x$, and this "almost all" depends on $x$. This is very annoying for me.

However, I also have the following estimate which I hope might save the day: 
$$\left\lVert S^\star v\right\rVert_2 \le C \lVert v \rVert_{H^s}, \qquad \forall v\ \text{ of Schwartz class},$$
which holds for some $s>0$. So I am able to take an approximating sequence $v_j$ such that 
$$\lVert S_tv_j- S_t v\rVert_2 \to 0\, \forall t \in (0,1), $$
and at the same time $S^\star v_j(x)$ converges to *something* for almost all $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$. From all of this originates my question.

Comment: What if you just define $f(x,t)=0$ for $x\not\in M_t$, so that the $f_t$ become defined everywhere?

Comment: @Etienne: Indeed, the way I have posed the question you are right. I am afraid that this will pose problems somewhere else, though. I am checking.